# Rails STI Subclasses get loaded when querying parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sti

I'm using STI pattern with Rails 6.0.3.3 and Ruby 2.6.6 which looks something like below:

```
class User end;

class User::Donor < User end;

class User::Legal < User::Donor end;
```

where donor and legal represents two types themselves.

I've inherited User::Legal with User::Donor due to the shared functionalities.

I've a `User::Legal` type record in my database.

In rails console when I try

```
1)  User::Donor.first # returns nil
2)  User::Legal.first # returns user_legal_obj
3)  User::Donor.first # returns user_legal_obj

// Query

1) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["type", "User::Donor"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

2) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["type", "User::Legal"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

3) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ($1, $2) LIMIT $3  [["type", "User::Donor"], ["type", "User::Legal"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Does anyone know why Rails is doing this weird behaviour that effects my output?

Comment: Nesting subclasses in the parent class seems like a good way to shoot yourself in the foot. Doing so with the scope resolution operator adds some extra excitement.

Comment: @max, can you please elaborate so I can acknowledge where exactly I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did not reproduce the inconsistent behavior in the description (two `User::Donor.first` prints different results). Were your files or database modified during your rails console session?

If you mean that getting `User::Donor` result when querying `User::Legal` is weird, the answer is: **it's expected behavior**, and that's why it's called 'inheritance'.

The concept is [from object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)), which means 'is a'. Here your `User::Legal` inherits from `User::Donor`, so `User::Legal` is a `User::Donor`. When querying `User::Donor` records, `User::Legal` should also be presented.

See 'Single table inheritance' in rails documents: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

Comment: Hey @qiu, no there were no changes made to the files during the console session plus, I agree with the inheritance concept but what I'm getting is the exact opposite of what you're saying.

I'm getting **User::Legal** object when I query on **User::Donor** see queries in the code snippet in the question's description.

Comment: In the code, `Legal` inherits from `Donor`. Imagine `Laptop` inherits from `Computer`, so if you're querying computers, laptops should also be in results. If you are filtering only `Donor` without subclasses, use `where('type = ?', 'User::Donor')`.